# nginx ssl wildcard cert issues

Tags: nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate

We currently have a single nginx server running as a backend proxy for 4-5 Apache servers.
my problem is that after installing the ssl certificate i get the following error when testing the ssl connection:
openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx:443 | more

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

The SSL was purchased through RapidSSL nginx's config is as follows for the ssl proxy:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name _;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl-access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/ssl-error.log;

        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate         ssl/wildcard-xxxxxxx.xx.xx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     ssl/wildcard-xxxxxxx.xx.xx.key;
        keepalive_timeout       60;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://backend;
        }
}
```

I can verify that the backend servers return the ssl connection ok

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

if anyone could give me a heads up or a pointed would be greatly appreciated.

Thnx,
David

Comment: Please check out what "server_name _;" does. It does not do what you think it does. Use "listen 443 default_server ssl;" instead. [Reference](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RapidSSL does not directly sign certificate by recognized Certificate Authority, but uses intermediate certiface to sign wildcard certificates. Browser / OpenSSL does not have intermediate certificate in it's trust chain, so it cannot validate SSL cert.

You have to install intermediate certificate in nginx. Get intermediate certificate (it should be included in your purchase / customer service instructions) and append it to your certificate.

```
 cat /path/to/intermediate.pem >> ssl/wildcard-xxxxxxx.xx.xx.crt
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your update, any idea where i can find this intermediate certificate? i can find the root one here: http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.cer but this don't seam to be working :S

Comment: http://notepad.cc/frosseetru61